# Niddah leftovers and "Shiirayim"

Tags: chasidut-hasidism, niddah, chassidic-rebbe

Is there any connection between the law that one may not eat a niddah's leftovers (שיריים) and the custom Chassidic custom of "Shiirayim" (שיריים)?

Comment: I assumed the Chassidic custom came from שירי המנחות